# How to display both home.php and index.php

Tags: homepage

Hey guys i recently created a theme. I want to show home.php when a visitor visit home page but all my blog posts are listed in index.php file. Can someone suggest me how to display index.php
i tried http://www.mysiteurl.com/index.php
but it redirecting me to http://www.mysiteurl.com/home.php
Please advise me. Thanks

Comment: we are already give the answers like these questions.so please don't repeat the questions.just check while you entering your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you fully understand the meaning of templates in WordPress. You do not choose template by including it in URL, WordPress deals with choosing template by making sense of URL request.

See [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in Codex.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can create an empty page and then under settings->reading settings you can set that newly created page to "display latest posts".  i think that should get that page to trigger index.php